# How to make Windows Community Toolkit datagrid editable in WinUI3 desktop app?

Tags: c#, datagrid, winui-3, windows-community-toolkit, windows-app-sdk

I am using Windows Community Toolkit datagrid in my WinUI3 desktop application. It works ok but I can't make it editable in-place though in [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid_guidance/editing_inputvalidation) they mention it should work.

```
 <controls:DataGrid FrozenColumnCount="3" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="False"
                    SelectionMode="Single"  ItemsSource="{Binding items}" >
        <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
        ...
        </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
</controls:DataGrid>
```

where

```
 private ObservableCollection<EditableRow> _items = new();
 public ObservableCollection<EditableRow> items
 {
     get => _items;
     set
     {
         SetProperty(ref _items, value, true);
         OnPropertyChanged(nameof(items));
     }
 }
```

and `EditableRow` implements `IEditableObject` interface. I think it is a binding issue, what could be wrong here?

Comment: After testing, the DataGrid control also supports cell and row editing functionality in Winui3 by default as @AndrewKeepCoding said. Could you please show a minimal, reproducible sample?

Comment: **[DataGridEditingUnit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid_guidance/editing_inputvalidation#enumerations)** enumeration specifies two editing levels, cell level and row level. You may try to make row's fields editable in case of your custom implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Columns are editable (`IsReadOnly=false`) by default. This works in my sample project.

```xml
<controls:DataGrid
    x:Name="DataGridControl"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    IsReadOnly="False"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items, Mode=OneWay}"
    SelectionMode="Single">
    <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
        <controls:DataGridTextColumn
            Binding="{Binding Id}"
            IsReadOnly="True" />
        <controls:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Title}" />
    </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
</controls:DataGrid>
```